# Scheduling passes in LLVM

Tags: clang, llvm

I do the following cloning for all arrays defined in my source code. 
For every array `A`, I create a copy `A'` and make all the basic blocks use `A'` and finally restore `A'` contents to `A`. This is perfectly possible writing a LLVM transformation pass using `IRBuilder.CreateMemcpy`

However, there is a scheduling problem when I register my custom pass with clang. Sometimes, it applies very late that causes `A` to marked read-only array and gives a run-time error when I do the restoration. If I schedule my pass very early [via `EP_AsEarlyAsPossible`], it screws up on loop info and other analysis that my custom pass depends on.

Can anyone help me resolve this scheduling issue?